# FInd the match data in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called Product. It has column called colors. It contains data as follows:

[image]

The data type for colors is `varchar`. The database contains large product values (almost 2 hundred) , and same applies to colors. Now I need to write an sql query script to find top 2 products having largest variation in colors.

Comment: Please, post your data as text. And what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Please don't *tag spam*, SQLLite <> MySql <> SQLServer, add the tag for your specific RDBMS

Comment: Why not fix your design and normalise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split and count the colors for each product(brand):

```
SELECT products, colors
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM([value]))) 
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(colors, 2, LEN(colors) - 2), ',')
         ) DESC
      ) AS rank
   -- FROM YourTable
   FROM (VALUES
      ('adidas', '{red, blue, black}'),
      ('puma', '{red, green, blue, orange}'),
      ('nike', '{red, green}')
   ) product (products, colors)
) t
WHERE rank <= 2
```

Result:

```
products colors 
----------------------------------
puma     {red, green, blue, orange}
adidas   {red, blue, black}
```

If you need to count the colors, simply add one additional column:

```
SELECT products, colors
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      (
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM([value]))) 
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(colors, 2, LEN(colors) - 2), ',')
      ) AS [count]
   FROM (VALUES
      ('adidas', '{red, blue, black, blue, red}'),
      ('puma', '{red, green, blue}'),
      ('nike', '{red, green}')
   ) product (products, colors)
) t
WHERE [count] > 2
```

Comment: the database is large and contains large product values (almost 2 hundred) , and same applies to colors. How can we optimize FROM (VALUES ('')) portion, since I cannot manually do that.

Comment: @manojadhikari that is the sample data you gave us, you wouldn't use a `VALUES` table construct you would use *your table* obviously.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks !! , since I am  new on this and learning can yo refactor that please using table name.

Comment: @Zhorov Thanks !! , since I am  new on this and learning can yo refactor that please using table name.

Comment: It's not my place to do that some one's answer, @manojadhikari , but it would just be `FROM dbo.YourTable`.

Comment: @Larnu How do I find  products that have variation more than 2

Comment: That's a different question, @manojadhikari, however, I suggest having a look at [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE(PRODUCT,COLOR) AS
(
  SELECT 'ADIDAS','{RED,BLUE}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'REEBOK','{PURPLE,GRAY,BLACK,ORANGE}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NIKE','{}'UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PUMA','{RED,BLACK,ORANGE}'
)
SELECT TOP 2 C.PRODUCT,C.COLOR,LEN(C.COLOR)XX
FROM CTE AS C
ORDER BY XX DESC
```

Could you please try if the above is suitable for you

Comment: I don't think this is suitable for large database where values of colors and products are in thousands.

Comment: No, the "best" solution would be to fix and normalise your design for the most performant solution, @manojadhikari .

Comment: not sure this would be reliable, eg {mustard yellow, chartreuse}, {red,blue,pink}